# SSIS: importing files some with column names, some without

Tags: header, ssis, dataflow

OrPresumably due to inconsistent configuration of logging devices, I need to load a collection of csv files via SSIS that will sometimes have a first row with column names and will sometimes not.  The file format is otherwise identical.

There seems a chance that the logging configuration can be standardized, so I don't want to waste programming time with a script task that opens each file and determines whether it has a header row and then processes it differently depending.

Rather, I would like to specify something like Destination.MaxNumberOfErrors, that would allow up to one error row per file (so if the only problem in the file was the header, it would not fail).  The Flat File Source error is fatal though, so I don't see a way of getting it to keep going.

> The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

My best choice seems to be to simply ignore the first data row for now and wait to see if a more uniform configuration can be achieved.  Of course, the dataset is invalid while this strategy is in place.  I should add that the data is very big, so the ETL routines need to be as efficient as possible.  In my opinion this contraindicates any file parsing or conditional splitting if there is any alternative.

The question is if there is a way to configure the File Source to continue from this fatal error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is!

In the "Error Output" page in the editor, change the Error response for each row to "Redirect row". Then you can trap the problem rows (the headers, in your case) by taking them as a single column through the error output of your source.

Comment: I looked at this.  I suppose this is the way to get the file import to continue.  Less than ideal for my purposes, but the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the values for header names would never appear in your data, then define your flat file connection manager as having no headers. The first step inside your data flow would check the values of column 1-N vs the header row values. Only let the data flow through if the values don't match.

Is there something more complex to the problem than that?